# parametrize url in JMeter with Switch Controller

Tags: jmeter

I testing in JMeter backend application, which using websocket connection  – in JMeter this is a plugin: Web Socket Sampler by Peter…….

I want  to parametrize following variables:

Host

Port

And securityKey let the can switch between them.

To can using 4 different host, four different securityKey.

I don’t want to use  any external files.

So I starting from defined user defined variables in Test plan, when I defined : host, port, and securityKey. I set following:

dev    dev.mycom.io         80

preprod preprod.mycom.io    80

prod    prod.mycom.io       80

localDev    local.mycom.com 8080

and then I must set this suitable for 3 different testing environment : development,production,

and next in WebScoket Open Connection I set: Server name or IP: ${host}  and Port: ${port}

I added Switch Controller, in which I added WebSocket request-response Sampler

But In SwitchControllet I don’t know how to set Switch Value, and I don’t know how I can set value for another environment.

How is the best way to parametrize this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Switch Controller is applicable here, I would recommend going for another approach, to wit:

1. Create several properties files, like:

   - `dev.properties`

     ```
     host=dev.mycom.io
     port=80
     ```
   - `prod.properties`

     ```
     host=prod.mycom.io
     port80
     ```
   - etc.
2. Add [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) to your Test Plan and refer the properties using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like `${__P(host,)}` and `${__P(port,)}`

   [image]
3. When you need to switch the environment you can pass the relevant .properties file to JMeter via [`-q` command line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -q dev.properties -t test.jmx
   ```

   or

   ```
   jmeter -q prod.properties -t test.jmx
   ```